# Function behaving differently when calling from a tk button vs calling directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having a really weird problem, i have this "product window" in my tkinter program, it is supposed to open when i press a button, but when i open it that way, the checkbuttons don't work properly

```
btn_mngProd=tk.Button(frm_left, text='Manage Products', font=("Tahoma",14),width=16,height=1, command=openProductsWindow)
btn_mngProd.pack(side='bottom',padx=10,pady=5,)
```

however, if i call the function simply by putting this in the "main area" of the code:
`openProductsWindow()`
it works properly

the "openProductsWindow" function is kinda big, so i won't put the entire thing here, but the most important thing is that, inside the function, there is a call to `renderTable(1)`, and inside the renderTable function, there is a call to `updateTable(page)`, which is the function that generates the checkbuttons, i'm saving all BooleanVar to each checkbutton in a list, but the problem starts when i try to read the value of each one of the 20s vars

```
def updateTable(page):
    #some code here
    global checkboxesVars
    checkboxesVars.clear()   
    rowCount=1
    for j in range((page-1)*20,page*20):
        
        #some code here

        checkboxesVars.append(tk.BooleanVar())
        cbx_prod=tk.Checkbutton(master=frm_table,bg="white",onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=checkboxesVars[rowCount-1], command=checkCheckboxes)
        cbx_prod.grid(row=rowCount, column=3,sticky='nesw',padx=1,pady=1)
        if(prodNumber > dataLenght):
            cbx_prod.configure(state='disabled')
        rowCount+=1
```

this is the function that checks how many checkboxes are pressed:

```
    global checkboxesVars
    checkeds=0
    for i in range(len(checkboxesVars)):
        print(i)
        cb_var=checkboxesVars[i]
        print(cb_var.get())
        if(cb_var.get()):
            checkeds+=1
```

i have both prints in there to help me debug, this is what is supposed to print when i check the first 3 boxes:

```
0
True
1
True
2
True
3
False
4
False...
```

and that's exactly what i get when i execute `openProductsWindow()` directly, but if i execute it by pressing the button, all 20 checkboxes vars appear as False, even if i check all of them

sorry for any english errors, i'm not a native speaker

Comment: Do you use `Tk()` for both the root window and *product window*?

Comment: yes, i use, is there a better way to do that? maybe a popup window

Comment: i did some research and came across the ```tk.Toplevel()```, i tested it and it works perfectly, thank you, but can anyone explain me what exactly could be the problem?

Comment: It is because those BooleanVars and the checkbuttons are in different `Tk()` instances and they cannot be connected to each others.